# Trino-ranger plugin not working on Trino 405 and Ranger 1.2.0

Tags: trino, apache-ranger

When trying to restart Trino 405 after installing Trino-ranger plugin on ranger 1.2.0 getting below error.

```
2023-06-24T01:28:06.086-0400    INFO    main    com.google.inject.Guice An exception was caught and reported. Message: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @6e997547
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:258)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:207)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.create(ProviderMethod.java:69)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.createProviderMethod(ProviderMethodsModule.java:272)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.getProviderMethods(ProviderMethodsModule.java:116)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.configure(ProviderMethodsModule.java:100)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:344)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:353)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:137)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
        at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initialize(Bootstrap.java:262)
        at org.apache.ranger.authorization.trino.authorizer.RangerSystemAccessControlFactory.create(RangerSystemAccessControlFactory.java:53)
        at io.trino.security.AccessControlManager.createSystemAccessControl(AccessControlManager.java:181)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance(Collections.java:4853)
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$2.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:4861)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
         at io.trino.security.AccessControlManager.loadSystemAccessControl(AccessControlManager.java:150)
        at io.trino.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:157)
        at io.trino.server.Server.lambda$start$0(Server.java:88)
        at io.trino.$gen.Trino_405____20230624_052740_1.run(Unknown Source)
        at io.trino.server.Server.start(Server.java:88)
        at io.trino.server.TrinoServer.main(TrinoServer.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate(DuplicatesPredicate.java:104)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CollectionUtils.filter(CollectionUtils.java:52)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:69)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @6e997547
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:149)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper.<clinit>(MethodWrapper.java:23)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @6e997547
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:52)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:67)
        ... 41 more


2023-06-24T01:28:06.105-0400    ERROR   main    io.trino.server.Server  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:51)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:48)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:155)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:581)
        at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor$1.run(AbstractBindingProcessor.java:176)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.initializeBindings(ProcessedBindingData.java:49)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:122)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
        at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initialize(Bootstrap.java:262)
        at org.apache.ranger.authorization.trino.authorizer.RangerSystemAccessControlFactory.create(RangerSystemAccessControlFactory.java:53)
        at io.trino.security.AccessControlManager.createSystemAccessControl(AccessControlManager.java:181)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance(Collections.java:4853)
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$2.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:4861)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
        at io.trino.security.AccessControlManager.loadSystemAccessControl(AccessControlManager.java:150)
        at io.trino.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:157)
        at io.trino.server.Server.lambda$start$0(Server.java:88)
        at io.trino.$gen.Trino_405____20230624_052740_1.run(Unknown Source)
        at io.trino.server.Server.start(Server.java:88)
        at io.trino.server.TrinoServer.main(TrinoServer.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:258)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:207)
        at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:49)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:156)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:92)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:37)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:40)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper
at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate(DuplicatesPredicate.java:104)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CollectionUtils.filter(CollectionUtils.java:52)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:69)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
        ... 47 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Last version of ranger is working with trino 402. So, you cannot use higher version of trino for now.